# Formalizing "Every Italian likes to eat pizza"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

> Every Italian likes to eat pizza.

In predicate logic, are these formalizations syntactically and semantically correct?

1. $$\forall x \forall y(\text{Italian}(x) \land \text{Pizza}(y) \implies \text{LikeToEat}(x,y))$$ ($∀x∀y \text{ Italian}(x)∧\text{Pizza}(y)⟹\text{LikeToEat}(x,y)$ should also be correct.)
2. $$\forall x: (\text{Italian}(x) \implies \text{LikeToEatPizza}(x))$$ (Is the colon's placement syntactically correct?)
3. $$\forall \text{italian} \in \text{Italian}:  \text{LikeToEatPizza}(\text{italian})$$
4. $$\forall i(  L(\text{pizza}))$$
5. $$\forall i: \text{EatingPizza}(x)$$
6. $$ \forall x: L(x) $$ ($x:$ Italian ; $L:$ likes to eat pizza)

Comment: 1. is too strong: it means every Italian likes to eat any pizza. 2. is better, but eliminate the colon. Also use the \text{} environment inside a math environment to make text non-italic.

Comment: 4. is wrongly written and 2. and 3. are "variants".

Comment: @AdrianKeister I have a question regarding of removing the parenthesis from 1. and 2.. That would make x and y unbound after AND  and the Implikation and would be wrong, right?
And about the colon: is this wrong or just not "beauty"?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA 1. and 2. withouth parenthesis around the formula would make both wrong, right?

Comment: Is there a rule to name predicates with capital letters?

Comment: @user3352632: Removing parentheses from 1 and 2 would degrade the answers, for sure, possibly making them syntactically incorrect. It depends a bit on which rules you're following. I would use your number 2, but write it like this: $(\forall\,x)(\operatorname{Italian}(x)\implies\operatorname{LikesToEatPizza}(x)).$

Comment: The colon is probably not syntactically correct according to whatever rules you have, but it might be ok. It's not ambiguous, certainly. I can read your number 2 and know unambiguously what it means. It might not fly with a computer, though. Depends on the computer.

Comment: Predicates usually are written with CamelCase, such as LikesToEatPizza.

Comment: @AdrianKeister thanks for your replies. I think:  $\forall x: Italian(x) \implies LikeToEatPizza(x)$ is also correct. The first one written as $\forall x \forall y Italian(x) \land Pizza(y) \implies LikeToEat(x,y)$ should be also correct. x and y are bounded in all occurences, right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA could you please take a look at the 5 and 6?

Comment: If you want to quantify pizza, use an existential rather than a universal. Because, liking pizza means that there is at least one pizza that you like, but not necessarily all.

Comment: Also, I see what you're doing with $:$ meaning "such that", and although this abbreviation is common, it's actually *not* a formal logic symbol, and is usually only used to save time / space, for verbal clarity, or as a separator. So putting it here is not strictly formal.

Comment: @Graviton "Every Italian likes pizza" is rather ambiguous: it is not inconsistent with every Italian liking every pizza, even Hawaiian. A similar issue (but in a bigger sentence) was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694129/21813).

Comment: @ryang Haha, agreed. At the least, it is safer to use an existential in a moment of ambiguity, as it will be implied by the stronger universal (assuming a non-empty universe, as Italians definitely exist).

Comment: @user3352632 Re: removing the parenthses: No, `∀x Px⇒Qx` does **not** mean `∀x(Px⇒Qx)`, but instead `(∀y Py)⇒Qx`.